# Скрыть/показать текст вместо картинки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Хочу, чтобы при наведении на псевдо-ссылку из верхнего меню показывался соответствующий ей текст, а картинка вместо него скрывалась. У меня получилось что-то похожее. Столкнулся с проблемой, что текст не встает на место картинки и пока обрабатывается скрипт съезжает нижний блок с контентом.

```
$('.spoiler').hide();
$('.pseudo-top-menu .pseudo-link').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        var index = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
        $('.t' +index).fadeOut();
        $('.t' +index+ '+.spoiler').fadeIn();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        var index = $(this).parent().index() + 1;

        $('.t' +index+ '+.spoiler').fadeOut();  
       $('.t' +index).fadeIn();
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/skdhd2ae/1/)

Comment: Переписать и сделать по-человечески на css не вариант?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рекомендую поставить над картинкой тексовый бок с `{position:absolue; z-index:2; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;}` (у `.teasers-menu li`, где они оба находятся - `position:relative;` соотв.) и при наведении менять его видимость/прозрачность, а картинку вообще не трогать (пусть просто под ним прячется и все)